# Confusions about function spectrum in Anderson duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, mathematical-physics, duality-theorems, spectra

In appendix B of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211216, Hopkins and Singer defined the Anderson dual $\tilde{I}(E)$ of a spectrum $E$ as the function spectrum of maps from $E$ to $\tilde{I}$, where $\tilde{I}$ is a spectrum called the Anderson dual of the sphere. Then they claimed that
$$[X, \tilde{I}(E)]=[X\wedge E, \tilde{I}].$$ And when we take $E$ to be the rational Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum $H\mathbb{Q}$, we have $\tilde{I}(E)=H\mathbb{Q}$.

To my understanding, this is something like $[A,[B, C]]=[A\wedge B, C]$, however, in the definition of function spectra I found on page 50 of this book https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/SymSpec-v3.pdf, $\tilde{I}(X)$ should be defined to be
$\mathrm{map} (E, \mathrm{sh}^n(\tilde{I}))$
on the $n$-th level, where $\mathrm{sh}$ shifts the level of spectra by one. It seems there is no "homotopy class" taken in the definition of function spectrum. But in some other contexts, some authors just define this function spectrum to be $[E, \tilde{I}]$. I am quite confused about if these definitions coincide and how to deduce the statements made by Hopkins and Singer.

Any comments or corrections are welcome!

Comment: It is true that $\pi_0\mathrm{map}(X,Y)$ is the group of homotopy classes of maps from $X$ to $Y$ (you might have to replace $X$ by a cofibrant and/or $Y$ by a fibrant spectrum).

Comment: Hi @Vincent! I am not so familiar with model categories, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The painless way to describe the function spectrum $F(X,Y)$ is that it is the representing object for the functor $Z \rightarrow [Z \wedge X,Y]$. Brown representability for spectra guarantees this is well defined in the homotopy category of spectra.

Comment: Thanks @Connor, could you recommend some materials on this fact? Also I still did't figure out how to deal with the $H\mathbb{Q}$ part though...

Comment: Using [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312618/sphere-spectrum-character-dual-and-anderson-dual) definition, I believe the reasoning is that the map $H\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}$ rationally is equivalent to $H\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow *$ which has fiber $H\mathbb{Q}$. And so rationally, Anderson duality is the same as $\operatorname{Map}(-,H\mathbb{Q})$ from which the result follow.

Comment: Sorry @Connor, I am a bit slow on homotopy theory and did not catch you. Could you explain a little bit the exact meaning of "the map $H\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow I_{\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}}$ rationally is equivalent to $H\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow *$" and how you deduce this from the definitions? Does this fact imply the two fibers $I_{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $H\mathbb{Q}$ agree in some sense?

Comment: Another way to look at it is this. Whatever model category of spectra you use, $\mathrm{map}(X,Y)$ is constructed in a way such that $\mathrm{map}(X,-)$ is right adjoint to $-\wedge X$ and this is even a Quillen adjunction (possibly after cofibrantly replacing $X$, I can never remember). A Quillen adjunction leads to a derived adjunction on the homotopy categories, so that is how you get what I wrote above. But of course derived adjunctions involve (co)fibrantly replacing objects, so there are some subtleties there.

Comment: Note that for example in orthogonal spectra the sphere spectrum is cofibrant.